# Sort a list based on repetition values

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, duplicates

I have a string list like this : {3,2,2,1,1,1,1,4,4,4} And i want sort it by number of repetition of values so that the be this {1,1,1,1,2,2,4,4,4,3} Thanks for you attenttion

Comment: don't understand, why is that the sorted list and not {1,1,1,1,4,4,4,2,2,3}???

Comment: Because 1 is writed 4 time , 4 repetition 3 time , 2 two time and 1 writed one time

Comment: so how does {1,1,1,1,2,2,4,4,4,3} make sense ?

Answer (score 3):

You can sort the list based on repetition using [Collections.frequency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-) with [Comparator.comparingInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
Comparator.comparingInt(i->Collections.frequency(list, i)).reversed()
```

Below is the example

```
    List<Integer>  list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(3,2,2,1,1,1,1,4,4,4));

    System.out.println(list);

    list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(i->Collections.frequency(list, i)).reversed());

    System.out.println(list);  //[1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3]
```

Instead of checking the frequency of each and every element in List, you can do it in other way by grouping the element and count into `Map<Integer, Long>` and then creating another sorted list [Collections.nCopies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies-int-T-)

```
List<Integer> result = list.stream()
                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()))
                       .entrySet()
                       .stream()
                       .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                       .map(entry->Collections.nCopies(entry.getValue().intValue(), entry.getKey()))
                       .flatMap(List::stream)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```